# What are the file download sizes for the OS's available on raspberrypi.org?

Tags: operating-systems, debian, archlinux, qtonpi

http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads currently has 3 linux distributions for download:

- Debian “squeeze” (recommended for people "just starting out")
- Arch Linux ARM
- QtonPi

Unfortunately they don't state the file sizes of these - can anyone tell me how big they are? This will be particularly important for low-bandwidth users.

It's also important to have an SD card that's big enough!

Comment: Every decent HTTP/BitTorrent client shows filesize when the download starts, so I don't see why is this so important though.

Comment: All the images are <2GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Debian download is 443.06 MB. A minimum 4Gb SD Card is recommended, but you may want to use a larger card (max 32Gb) to allow room for adding software and growth of your log files.

Note under Debian you will need to resize the SD Card to make use of alll the space available on your SD Card. You can find instructions on doing this [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4VovMDnsIE).

The Arch Linux download is 201.82 MB. and the QtonPi download is 741.18 MB.